# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'range'

Tags: python, parameter-passing, wrapper

```
import datetime

def logger(fn):
 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
  print(f"{fn.__name__} : {args} | {kwargs}")
  start = datetime.datetime.now()
  ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  delta = datetime.datetime.now()
  print(f"The function takes {(delta - start).total_seconds()} seconds")
  return ret
 return wrapper

@logger  # add=logger(add)
def add(*args, **kwargs):
 return sum(args) + sum(kwargs.values())

print(add(range(100)))
```

This is the effects

```
add : (range(0, 100),) | {}
```

When I tried to run the code, it will report an error.

```
    return sum(args) + sum(kwargs.values())
           ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'range'
```

Changing `sum(args)` to `sum(*args)` will solve the problem, but I want to know why, as `sum(range(10))` is totally Ok and why would it fail in a wrapper?

Comment: `args` is the tuple `(range(100), )`, not the single value `range(100)`. You can sum the elements of a `range` object, but you cannot sum `range` objects themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have made a ridiculous mistake. The args in the program is `(range(100),)`. It is a tuple, not simple 'range(100)`. So I must destruct it with` *`.

Comment: Moreover, I should change the call of the function instead of the function itself. Just as `print(add(*range(10)))`